# What did Team Rocket use to evolve Rhyhorn?

Tags: pokemon

In the Pokemon Adventures manga, [Koga](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Koga) used some kind of item (like a syringe) on his Rhyhorn:

[image]

The strange part is that the Rhyhorn suddenly evolved into a Rhydon, in the middle of the fight:

[image]

Red confirmed this:

[image]

I didn't understand how it would be possible to make Rhyhorn to evolve like this, because Rhyhorn is not the kind of Pokemon that could be evolved by stones.

So what did Team rocket use? Does this item appear again in the manga and did someone explain it better? Or does it even exist in the TV series?

Comment: I'd like to know how he got that syringe in to the rhyhorn.

Comment: @Krazer♦ That's a good question

Comment: Maybe it was a ton of liquid Rare Candies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No reliable site lists what that syringe is (or could be) and it never appeared again. Misty asumes that an other of these syringes was used to evolve a gyarados (seen earlier).

Team Rocket tried to create ways to force an evolution (like the experiments at the lake of rage), so it's most likely another experiment to force the evolution of a pokémon and to make it stronger.